# Starvation in dining philosopher's solution

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, monitor

I have gone through the [dining philosophers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) solution. Since at some point of time the typical monitor implementation causes starvation. I have gone through the "Polite" version of Dining-philosopher's problem given [here](http://vip.cs.utsa.edu/nsf/pubs/starving/starving.html)

```
monitor diningPhilosophers {
   int[] state = new int[5];
   boolean[] leftHungry = new boolean[5];
   boolean[] rightHungry = new boolean[5];
   static final int THINKING = 0;
   static final int HUNGRY = 1;
   static final int EATING = 2;
   condition[] self = new condition[5];

   public diningPhilosophers {
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
         state[i] = THINKING;
         leftHungry[i] = false;
         rightHungry[i] = false;
      }  
   }   

   public entry pickUp(int i) {
      state[i] = HUNGRY;
      test(i);
      if (state[i] != EATING)
         self[i].wait;
      rightHungry(left(i)) = false;
      leftHungry(right(i)) = false;
   }

   ublic entry putDown(int i) {
      state[i] = THINKING;
      test(left(i));
      if (state[left(i)] == HUNGRY)
         leftHungry[i] = true;
      test(right(i));
      if (state[right(i)] == HUNGRY)
         rightHungry[i] = true;
   }

   private test(int i) {
      if  (state[right(i] != EATING) &&
          (state[i] == HUNGRY) &&
          (state[left(i)] != EATING) &&
             !leftHungry(i) && !rightHungry(i) ) {
             state[i] = EATING;
             self[i].signal;
          }
   }

   private int left(int i) {
      return (i+1)%5;
   }    

   private int right(int i) {
      return (i+4)%5;
   }    

}
```

So what if 2 adjacent philosophers are hungry at the same time. Since the test(i) is checking whether its left and right philosophers are hungry. If it finds that its adjacent one is also hungry. It is kind of a deadlock right? I mean both of them can never eat since their adjacent philosopher's are hungry right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Deadlock would occur if two adjacent philosophers were hungry in *each other's eyes*, ie. `leftHungry[0] == TRUE && rightHungry[1] == TRUE`.

**However**, this state could never occur because the only time `leftHungry[x]` or `rightHungry[x]` are set to `TRUE` is when `x` calls `putDown()`, which is always preceded by `x`'s call to `pickUp()`, which sets `leftHungry[x]` and `rightHungry[x]` to `FALSE`.

**For example:** `philosopher0` has `leftHungry[0] == TRUE` and their state is `HUNGRY`, and `philosopher1` calls `pickUp()` and their state is then `HUNGRY` too. Even if `philosopher1` must wait, (because `philosopher2` is `EATING`), `philosopher0` sets `leftHungry[0] == FALSE`, preventing any adjacent philosophers from simultaneously *thinking* each other is hungry.